# Unable to extract year from datetime function python

Tags: python

Im just starting out on basics of python . Im trying to get the output to say "'User' is now '25' years old .'User' will be 100 years old in 'Year' " .

In my extraction i am unable to obtain the 'year' in the output.Below is my code .Please advise!

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
name=input("Enter you name : ")
age=input("Enter your age : " )
years_left=(100-int(age))
dates=datetime.now()+timedelta(days=365*years_left)
years=dates.year
string="{} is now {} years old.{} will be 100 years old in "
output=string.format(name,age,name,years)
print(output)
```

Comment: Try using: `string="{} is now {} years old.{} will be 100 years old in {}"`

Comment: oops missed my place holder :D ! thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

It is in general a good habit to map your inputs by `enumerating` it, you can do it as follows.

```
string="{0} is now {1} years old.{3} will be 100 years old in {4}"
output=string.format(name,age,name,years)
```

Comment: or use keywords: `"{name} is now {age} years old. {name} will be 100 years old in {years}".format(name=name, age=age, years=years)`

Answer (score 0):

Formatter for string is missing.

Try the following definition.

```
string="{} is now {} years old.{} will be 100 years old in {}"
```